# Generate tests for a backtrack code

Tags: testing

I have a piece of code, let's say a function `foo`, which uses backtracking to solve a problem. `foo` finds the minimal number of actions to perform so as to reach a desired state.

Thus, any brute-force try would look more or less the same as my code. Is there any way to generate automatic tests for such a problem?

Comment: Why does the type of solution (backtracking in this case) perfect you from testing?

Comment: Normally, I'd use a brute force solution to generate the results and compare them with my "clever" algorithm. But when brute force doesn't differ much from the backtrack solution, I doesn't seem of much sense to use it for testing

Comment: When you design your tests, you should define the cases you want to test. It's likely you'll use static data (input, required output) for this. I don't see how this stops working in this case.

Comment: I'd like to generate 1000 tests with the expected results. I won't write 1000 tests by hand ;)

Comment: So either create a piece of code that generates this once, and use the result every time, or create a piece of code that generates a deterministic set of tests and results and run that.